# Encrypted zip file, prior to php 7.2

Tags: php, encryption, zip

I have to unpack an encrypted zip file directly in PHP, but we are running php 7.1 with no current scheduled update to 7.2 and the newer libzip. 
Is there no way to get it done with php 7.1?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Creating encrypted ZIP files with password in PHP

You need at least PHP 7.2 to encrypt ZIP files with a password.

[Link](https://gist.github.com/odan/890ee6bb265b2c836e4eb87d482fb948)